# Why aren't local UDP packets delivered?

Tags: .net, vb.net, udp, udpclient

I'm trying to write a very simple UDP client/server pair that will work together on the same computer (for now), but none of my packets are being delivered.  The code below is a 100% complete VB.NET console application.  It runs without throwing errors, but the mListener.Receive command never returns.

Question 1: Why am I not receiving any packets?

Question 2: Why can't I have my Client use IPAddress.Any as an end point?  When I try to connect to New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 10123), I get a "The requested address is not valid in its context 0.0.0.0:10123" exception.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim ep As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 10123)
        Dim s As New Server(ep)
        Dim c As New Client(ep)
        Do
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting in main loop...")
            Thread.Sleep(5000)
        Loop
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class Server
    Private mBroadcaster As UdpClient

    Public Sub New(ep As IPEndPoint)
        mBroadcaster = New UdpClient
        mBroadcaster.ExclusiveAddressUse = False
        mBroadcaster.Connect(ep)
        Dim sender As New Thread(AddressOf SendLoop)
        sender.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SendLoop()
        Do
            Dim msg As Byte() = Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello world")
            Console.WriteLine("Sending...")
            mBroadcaster.Send(msg, msg.Length)
            Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Client
    Private mListener As UdpClient

    Public Sub New(ep As IPEndPoint)
        mListener = New UdpClient
        mListener.ExclusiveAddressUse = False
        mListener.Connect(ep) 'Why can't I use IPAddress.Any here?
        Dim poller As New Thread(AddressOf PollLoop)
        poller.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PollLoop()
        Do
            Dim ep As IPEndPoint = Nothing
            Console.WriteLine("  Receiver listening...")
            Dim incomingbytes As Byte() = mListener.Receive(ep)
            Dim msg As String = Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(incomingbytes)
            Console.WriteLine("  Received: " & msg & " from " & ep.Address.ToString & ":" & ep.Port)
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You can't "connect" to "0.0.0.0" because you can't send anything there. What would sending a packet to "Any" mean? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok, then how do I start up my Client's mListener?  If I don't use .Connect, then .Receive throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why the original code doesn't work, but I did find a way to accomplish what the original code intends.  The basic idea is that it's apparently fine to use a UdpClient for the server, but it's not ok to use a UdpClient for...the client.  Instead, I changed the UdpClient to a lower-level Socket.  I suspect it would also be fine to replace the Server's UdpClient with a Socket as well, but I haven't tested that.  This also resolves question 2 (the raw Socket allows for listening on IPAddress.Any).

I would still accept a different answer that actually explains why this is the case.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim s As New Server
        Dim c As New Client
        Do
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting in main loop...")
            Thread.Sleep(5000)
        Loop
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class Server
    Private mBroadcaster As UdpClient

    Public Sub New()
        mBroadcaster = New UdpClient
        mBroadcaster.ExclusiveAddressUse = False
        mBroadcaster.Connect(New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 10123))
        Dim sender As New Thread(AddressOf SendLoop)
        sender.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SendLoop()
        Do
            Dim msg As Byte() = Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello world")
            Console.WriteLine("Sending...")
            mBroadcaster.Send(msg, msg.Length)
            Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Client
    Private mListener As Socket

    Public Sub New()
        mListener = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)
        mListener.ExclusiveAddressUse = False
        mListener.Bind(New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 10123))
        Dim poller As New Thread(AddressOf PollLoop)
        poller.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PollLoop()
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(1023) {}
        Do
            Console.WriteLine("  Receiver listening...")
            Dim nbytes As Integer = mListener.Receive(buffer)
            Dim msg As String = Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, nbytes)
            Console.WriteLine("  Received: " & msg)
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```